# jQuery - Can't show dropdown list upon clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header and am trying to create a drop-down menu without Bootstrap.

When I click on a link, I want the drop-down menu to appear. It's hidden by default. I tried using jQuery to show the list.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
     <div class="menu_center">
       <a href="#">Products</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stationary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a>
         </ul>

       <a href="#">Promotions</a>

       <a href="#">About Us</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Suppliers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>

       <a href="#">Your Cart:</a>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Tech{Yourself} T-Shirt: Blue, Large - $19.95</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tech{Yourself} Owl Plush Toy - $19.95</a></li>
           <li><b>Total: $39.90</b> <button class="js-check-out">Check Out</button></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
html body{
    font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:400;
}

.menu_center a {
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_center ul").hide();
    $(".menu_center > a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).children("ul").show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ov9za3r/1/

Not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: While I like that you want to do this without Bootstrap, you might still want to look at how they structured the markup. The `<ul><li><a>Parent</a><ul>Children</ul></li></ul>` is a great pattern to use because it will easily allow for a CSS only nav (if you want a fallback).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ul` element is not a child of the `a` element, you would need to do:

```
$(this).next("ul").show();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ov9za3r/2/)

Comment: Deleted my answer and added the jsfiddle to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$(this).children("ul").show();
```

by this:

```
$(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
```

The `ul` is not the children, its the next element right after the `a` tag

and you might want to use `toggle()`, `fadeToggle()` or `slideToggle()` rather than just `show()` to be able to hide the menu again when u click on it after it appears

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/9ov9za3r/4/)